# A ServiceWorker intercepted the request and encountered an unexpected error

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I recently implemented Angular service workers in my web app and when I reload my app in some routes, I get this error and the site stucks in `app-shell`:

```
Failed to load ‘https://<my-test-domain>/runtime.4c3f9e771b5d653d.js’. A ServiceWorker intercepted the request and encountered an unexpected error.
```

For example when I reload on `https://<my-test-domain>/landing` it works fine.

But when I reload on `https://<my-test-domain>/chat/123456` the error will show in console. *(123456 is a p2p thread id in chat section)*

My `ngsw-config.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "appData": {
    "version": "3.2.3",
    "changeList": [],
    "force": false
  },
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.json",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your service worker configuration?

Comment: added. @VimalPatel